# How can I save a changelist state in WebStorm without committing them nor resetting the changes?

Tags: git, save, webstorm

I want to save (back up) temporary states of WIP on complex feature development without committing them. This is specially useful on exploration work, when you figure out this solution path is not the best and want to continue from a specific point.

You can [stash or shelve a changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/stashing-and-unstashing-changes.html) on WebStorm, but both features reset the state to `HEAD`, which causes issues on my hot deploy feature, plus the extra work to unstash or unshelve.

I also notice that [putting labels](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/putting-labels.html) is only usable for changes on a single file and [tags](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/adding-tags.html) only work for committed changes.

Answer (score 1):

> w/o committing

Yet, simply [commit in Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/committing-changes-to-a-local-git-repository.html), and then change your code.

You can do an [interactive rebase](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/interactive-rebase.html) (still in Webstorm) later, in which you will drop those intermediate commits, or squash together other intermediate commits.

That way (commit, plus refactoring), you don't have any hot deploy issue when saving your WIP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, dear @VonC. Just to clarify a perhaps informal abbreviation:   "w/o committing" meant "without committing". I edited the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am familiar with that abbreviation. The point of this answer is to point out you *should* commit.

Comment: Oh! My apology! So (1) you mean commit on the local repository until I'm ready? (2) I haven't tried interactive rebase through WebStorm and will give it a try.

Comment: And also the reasons I wanted to avoid committing were:
 (a) I don't want to commit something that may be throw away  – perhaps there is a psychological effect of the word "commit" :-)

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, a commit is by definition local. It does not mean it will appear on a remote repo, not before you push it.

Comment: @Ricardo no problem: a commit can very much be a temporary or intermediate state: the interactive rebase is there to allow you to re-do those commits as you want before publishing (pushing) them out.

Comment: (b) usability: I use the `Version Control > Log` panel to manage my commits and the `Version Control > Shelf` to manage exploratory work

Comment: @Ricardo in your case, commit is easier: no HEAD reset, and you can go on immediatly after the commit. Once you are done, an interactive rebase will allow you to reshape that history.